# Clicking "Downloads" in Finder does nothing. How can I repair it?

Tags: finder

When I click the Downloads item in the Finder, it does nothing.

The previously highlighted item remains highlighted.

[image]

How can I fix this?

If I open a console/bash prompt I can see that `~/Downloads` exists.  The mode is 755 and I am the owner.

Comment: Do the other Favorites still work? Does opening your home folder and then double-clicking the Downloads folder *in the Finder window* work (should open the folder and select Downloads in the sidebar)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the problem was.

When I went back and clicked again, it worked as before.

a puzzle.

Comment: Oddly good advice. Sometimes things get wedged in a temporary state, and a reboot or just a pause clears things up. This is why troubleshooting almost always recommends you reboot and make sure the issue is reproducible. Only time will tell if this comes back, but just knowing that it can come and go will help if it does reappear.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two different ways to address this:

**Method A)**

1. **Remove the "Downloads" icon from the side bar** (hold the cmd key, drag it out of the side bar)
2. Navigate to your home folder, and **drag the "Downloads" folder back to the side bar**

**Method B)** *Caution: this will completely reset any changes you made to the Finder sidebar*

1. Go to your user's "Library" folder (in Finder, hold the "Alt" key, and and pull down the "Go" menu at the top of the screen. You should see "Library" as one of the options)
2. **In ~/Library/Preferences folder, move "com.apple.sidebarlists.plist" to the Trash**
3. reboot (or log out of your account, and then log back in again)